# TFS Build Error - WPF with Reference Libraries

Tags: dll, tfs, msbuild

I have a project that makes use of three different additional reference libraries. The project compiles and runs correctly with all actions behaving as expected for the libraries (PulseButton, Log4Net & WpfAnimatedGif). However as soon as I try to build the project through TFS 2015 I get an error:

[image]

If I take out all references to the PulseButton from the project, I get the same error for the next Reference Library I have introduced to the project.

I have checked the actual file locations for the References and all seems to be in order there as well.

[image]

I am referencing in the XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="frmMain" x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ePortfolio_Client"
        xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"    
        xmlns:pb="clr-namespace:NMT.Wpf.Controls;assembly=PulseButton"
        Title="t2 - ePortfolio" Height="740" Width="1370" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Icon="Content/Portfolio.ico" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >
```

I appreciate this is quite a vague question but am a bit stuck. Any help on what might be causing my problems is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

After a little bit of snuffling around I have a feeling it is to do with the DLLs not being installed on the TFS server. I am guessing I need to install these through Visual Studio?  Any other help here would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Silly really - should have tried this before testing... My Edit above was hinting down the right path. My Build Definition is working at Project Level (instead of Solution) so the DLLs installed through NuGet were not being picked up. NuGet installs in a Packages folder on the root of the solution... This was not being carried over.

I created a new folder in the Project and moved the DLLd there. I then went to the Project properties and updated the Reference Paths and all seemed to be fine.

Now im getting an error regarding the Signing Certificate due to it being password protected... Nearly there!